# ¿Porque no ejecuta la función las veces que se ejecuta un for, jquery?

Tags: javascript, array

Con esta función, recorro un arreglo de objetos que contiene 3 items:
el detalle que la funcion `eliminarCupon`solamente se ejecuta en el primer objeto que encuentre.
Este es el objeto:     `{codCupon: "196923", codigo: "30025", precio: "99.4", cantidad: 1, idPedido: "72799"}`

```
function deleteItemGeneral(list, removeItem){
        console.log(list);
       for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ){
            if(list[i].codCupon == removeItem){             
                eliminarCupon(list[i].idPedido, list[i].codigo, list[i].tipocosto, list[i].precio,list[i].volumennegocio, -1, list[i].cod_cliente, list[i].tipo_cliente, list[i].codCupon, list[i].tipo_seleccion);
                console.log(i);
                list.splice(i,list.length);
               //console.log(list[i].codCupon);
               //break;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A medida que avanza, el splice quita elementos de list y reduce el length, por lo que la cantidad de iteraciones no coincide con el tamaño inicial de la lista.

En tu caso, el splice(i.length), quitara todos los elementos de la lista luego del 1er match del if, reduciendo el length de list a 1.

Dejo un pequeño ejemplo en donde se aprecia esta situacion:

```
function deleteTest (filtered) {
     var list = [1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5];
     for (i in list) { 
       console.log(i+":"+list.length);
       if (list[i]==filtered) { 
          list.splice(i, 1) 
       }
     }
     return list; 
   }

//output:
x = deleteTest(3);
0:8
1:8
2:7 
3:6
4:5 // Aquí, ya deja de evaluar la lista... y el resultado es [1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Ésta respuesta es correcta, agrego que puedes usar slice en éste caso ya que no modifica el array original.

Answer (score 0):

a menos de que la funcion `eliminarCupon` haga algo más, solo hazle el splice a `list` cuando en el `if` haga match con el valor de `removeItem`

```
function deleteItemGeneral(list, removeItem){
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].codCupon === removeItem) {
      list.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

saludos